# How to download the files that stored at particular location at Mongo DB

Tags: angularjs

I have uploaded my files in folder name uploads using the ng-file-upload with node.js and angularjs. Now I want to download those files whichever is clicked.

Now i have two Queries

1. How to show those files at client side
2. how to get the response i.e URL of the stored location of files so i can try to download.

Or is there any other process to show and download the files using the angularjs and nodejs.

Any hint will great help.